# Change the mouse cursor on a window from another process on Windows

Tags: windows, winapi, mouse-cursor

I have a process A, that launches a process B. I load a mouse cursor in A, and I want A to change the mouse cursor when the mouse is on the B window. Is it possible?

I tried to call [SetCursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648393%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from A when the mouse is over B, but even if I handle the [WM_SETCURSOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message in B, the cursor never changes. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way a window can control the mouse when it's over another window is by capturing the mouse (see [SetCapture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646262%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), or by setting the system mouse, but I very much doubt you want to do the latter.

Unfortunately capturing the mouse means you get all the mouse events sent to your window rather than theirs, so their GUI is unusable.

The only other solution is API hooking and code injection into B where you manage any messages such as WM_MOUSEMOVE and call SetCursor from within the application itself, possibly using some method of interprocess communication to get what cursor to set from application A.

Comment: Using SetCapture would not be a problem for me, because A already handles events and drawing on the window; but the problem is that it seems that SetCapture only works on top level windows.

Answer (score 1):

Applications are in control of their own cursors. Calling `SetCursor()` cannot from A cannot possibly work. Notice that `SetCursor()` has no parameters specifying which application the change is to be made to. This is because the change is made in the calling application.

You will need to inject code into B to effect the desired change.

Comment: I can code the feature into B instead of injecting code. But the problem is that I must inject the data into B, because my cursor is loaded in A, not B.

Comment: You'll just have to find a way to load it in B. That should be your question.

Comment: I wanted to avoid this, but it seems I have no other choice.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the child process' default cursor using `SetClassLong` with `GCL_HCURSOR`. This won't affect what's displayed when the child uses `SetCursor` to explicitly change its own cursor though, just the default that's displayed when it hasn't specified anything else. Warning: it's possible that a program may never display its default cursor at all, in which case this won't have any effect.

Comment: I already tryied, but because my cursor is loaded in A, it seems that the handle is invalid in B, so it does not work.